# CakePHP3 routing: pass static variable to controller action

Tags: cakephp, routes, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I trying to pass "language" param from CakePHP3 route, to the action, so I can set the language for those pages.

```
$routes->connect('/es/hola', ['controller' => 'StaticPages', 'action' => 'welcome']);
$routes->connect('/en/hello', ['controller' => 'StaticPages', 'action' => 'welcome']);
```

The only way I can make it work is using a dynamic parameter like this:

```
$routes->connect('/:lang/hola', ['controller' => 'StaticPages', 'action' => 'welcome'], ['pass' => ['lang']]);
```

But the problem is this route will be match:

```
/en/hola
/es/hello
...
/fr/hello
```

I think it should be another best way to do this in CakePHP3, but I can't find this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want it to be dynamic, then you need to pass it in the defaults, ie alongside the controller and action:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/es/hola',
    [
        'controller' => 'StaticPages',
        'action' => 'welcome',
        'lang' => 'es'
    ]
);
```

In the controller the parameter will be available via the request object:

```
$lang = $this->request->getParam('lang'); // param('lang') before CakePHP 3.4
```

If you want it to be passed as an argument to the controller action, you can still define it to be passed via the `pass` option.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Connecting Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration)**
- **[API > \Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder::connect()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Routing.RouteBuilder.html#_connect)**